# Trying to use sed to convert temperature from sensors command to number

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a script that I wrote for OS X using 'tempmonitor' that I'm trying to convert for use with lm-sensors under Ubuntu.

This is the original OS X script, reading ambient sensor temperatures on XServe inlets:

```
#!/bin/bash

/Users/admin/TemperatureMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/tempmonitor -f -a -l | grep AMBIENT > /tmp/temperature.txt

    filecontent=( `cat "/tmp/temperature.txt" `)

    temp1=`echo "${filecontent[3]} * 10 "|bc | sed 's/[.].*//'`
    temp2=`echo "${filecontent[10]} * 10 "|bc | sed 's/[.].*//'`


    if  (( $temp1 >= 900 || $temp2 >= 900 )); then
            EMAIL="network.services@domain.com"
            SUBJECT="MAIL01 INLET TEMPERATURE EXCEEDED!"
            mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < /tmp/temperature.txt
    fi
```

Earlier today I refined it to run on a couple of iBooks, placing a "temp" file into a local directory, rather than writing to /tmp:

```
#!/bin/bash
# define output text file
OUTFILE='/Users/macadmin/batterysensortemp.txt'

# define email headers
SUBJECT="BATTERY TEMPERATURE EXCEEDED!"
RECIPIENTS="admin@domain.net"

# get the current battery sensor temperature and save it to a text file
/Users/macadmin/TemperatureMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/tempmonitor -a -l | grep -i BATTERY > $OUTFILE

filecontent=(`cat $OUTFILE`)

temp1=`echo "${filecontent[1]}"|bc | sed 's/[.].*//'` #echo $temp1

if (( temp1 >= 33 )); then
    mail -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENTS < $OUTFILE
fi
```

So, turning to Linux, specifically Xubuntu 12.04, I installed lm-sensors. When running the "sensors" command, this is the output that I get:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +74.0Â°C  (crit = +103.0Â°C)
temp2:        +51.0Â°C  (crit = +115.0Â°C)
temp3:        +25.4Â°C  (crit = +103.0Â°C)
```

Now previously, all I had to deal with was a decimal point, so after reading in each line of output, the sed code read:

```
temp1=`echo "${filecontent[1]}"|bc | sed 's/[.].*//'`
```

But here I need to get rid of the + sign, the degree symbol, the capital letter C and whatever is causing that capital A. I have tried:

```
temp1=`echo "${filecontent[1]}"|bc | sed 's/[+.Â°C].*//'`
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \302
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \260
```

What *should* I be putting into the sed script to get the output I want, namely 740, 510, and 254? Or should I forget making up my own temperature sensor notification script and find something else (as ultimately that's what this is for)?

Update: With some of the feedback here, I've whipped up a new file from scratch on my home laptop, running Sabayon 13.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define email headers
SUBJECT="LAPTOP SENSOR TEMPERATURE EXCEEDED!"
RECIPIENTS="john@net.net"

temp1=`sensors | grep -i temp3 | grep -o '+[0-9.]\+' | sed '1~2!d; s/+//'`
temp2=`echo "$temp1 * 10" | bc | sed 's/[.].*//'`

if (( temp2 >= 330 )); then
echo "EMAIL ALERT TRIGGERED!"
#mail -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENTS < $OUTFILE 
fi
```

The variable temp1 gets a result of 24.0 (degrees C). Then I can multiply it by ten, giving temp2 240, compare that against 330, and since it's cooler, nothing gets triggered. This worked on Xubuntu as well without modifications! I think the trouble I was having with the garbage characters could be blamed on Putty on Windows 8, not the Xubuntu system I'm using at work. Thanks everyone for the help and pointers!

Comment: Looks like a character encoding issue...

Comment: Check your terminal settings.

Comment: What is the `|bc|` for? I suspect it is that, not sed, which is complaining

Comment: Please (a) copy your complete script into the question without destroying the original information, and then (b) delete your comment with the script in it, and (c) flag this comment as obsolete.  You can, and should, update your question when appropriate, remembering not to destroy what people have already discussed in their answers.  (If you need to add notes, by all means do so.)

Answer (score 1):

This outputs only the numbers:

```
sensors | grep -o '+[0-9.]\+' | sed '1~2!d; s/+//'
```

The grep part only prints the floating numbers preceded by `+`, while the sed part deletes each second line and removes the `+`.

Comment: That's saving me from having to write to a file, that's really cool, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The output is UTF-8 being interpreted as ISO 8859-1; that's where the Â° comes from.

Using `sed`, I'd probably use:

```
sed 's/^.*:[^0-9]*+\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]\).*/\1\2/'
```

The pattern looks for anything up to a colon, a series of non-digits, a plus sign (optionally use `[-+]` to look for negative numbers too, if you could be dealing with freezing temperatures), then remembers a sequence of digits, matches a dot, and remembers another digit, followed by anything; it replace that with the remembered digits.

Comment: I'm going to have to try this when I'm back at the office and have the Ubuntu box nearby; I'm running a different Linux here at home - 'sensors' still works, but I'm not getting the ISO 8859-1 output. Thanks Jonathan!

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed

```
>sed -n '/^temp.*/ s/[.].*//;s/+//p' file

temp1:        74
temp2:        51
temp3:        25
```